# Determine the image of $\{|z|< 1 ; 0 < \arg(z) \leq \pi/2 \}$ under $f(z) = -2z^3$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(z) = -2(z^3)$. Determine the image of the quarter disk $\{|z|< 1 ; 0 < \arg(z) \leq \pi/2 \}$under $f$.

I am not really sure where to start, is the image another name for the range ?

Comment: Yes, image is range. To solve this, first figure out what is happening to the boundary of this quarter disc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: work in polar coordinates. If $z=re^{i\theta}$, then
$$
f(z) = -2z^3 = 2e^{i\pi}\cdot r^3e^{3i\theta}
$$

Comment: What do you do with this now though?