# Describing image - Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

The question has $f(z) = -2z^3$ for $z$ in the quarter-disk $D$ given by $\lbrace z\in {\mathbb C}: 0<|z|<2$ and $ \dfrac{\pi}{2}< Arg(z)<\pi \rbrace$. Describe the image $S$ of $D$ under $f$.

I know what $D$ looks like but no clue about S...

Comment: First try to see how the image of $D$ looks under $z \mapsto z^3$. Polar coordinates may be helpful there.

Comment: like $f(D)$ implies $0< 2|z|^3<(2)2^3$ ?

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510736/) is very similar

Answer (score 1):

First, you can describe the domain $\lbrace z\in {\mathbb C}: 0<|z|<2, \ \pi/2<\arg z<\pi\rbrace$ in term of polar coordinates as
$$\lbrace re^{i\theta}:  0<r<2, \ \pi/2<\theta<\pi\rbrace$$
Second, $f(re^{i\theta})= -2r^3 e^{3i\theta} = 2r^3 e^{i (3\theta+\pi)} $. So, the new polar radius is $2r^3$ and the new polar angle is $3\theta+\pi$. 
Therefore, the points in the image will have polar radius between $0$ and $2 \cdot 2^3$ and the polar angle between $ 3 \pi/2 + \pi$ and $3 \pi +\pi$. (You should subtract $2\pi$ from these angle values to bring them into a more reasonable form).